# Error while uploading shapefile into Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, import, landsat

I have been trying to upload a shapefile "Phu Quoc" to Google Earth Engine and hence filtering the images based on this shp, however I've got this error:

> "Landsat Collection: Layer Error: Image.Visualize: No band named 'B5'

(the picture below), although `'B5'` is still available.

[image: example]

Could anyone please help me to figure out the problem, since I couldn't found any related post to this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify the bands you want to use, you have to do it by using square brackets and single commas like this:

`Map.addLayer(yourCollection, {min:0, max:5000, bands: ['B6', 'B5', 'B4']});`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about it.
Example:

```
  var study = table;//containing your shapefile
  var l8  = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
  .filterBounds(geometry)//editable
  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')//editable, based on the year your want
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER');
   print(l8);

   var sort = l8.toList(100); //all the imagery within that year will present
   var clip = ee.Image(sort.get(0)).clip(table); // you can change number to sort through the available imagery present 
   Map.addLayer(clip, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:3000}, 'table');// the bands here are the band combination
   //NB: satellite images that ends with SR(min: 0 ,max: 3000) and those with TOA(min: 0,max: 0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the images that intersect `table`, use `imageCollection.filterBounds(table)`.  If you need to clip for some reason, use `clipToCollection(table)`.